# installing net-snmp with V3 support on windows to use as mgmt tool for making requests to remote systems

Tags: windows, open-source, net-snmp, snmpv3

I am trying to make an snmpget request on a Windows 10 system to a system that only has SNMPv3 enabled.

I have installed net-snmp-5.7.0-1.x86.exe onto Windows 10.
During the installation, I check the "Encryption Support" checkbox.
It states "OpenSSL does not appear to be installed..." even though I have it installed.
Possibly to a different path. I continue to install.
An snmpget -v2c requests works ok, but V3 fails:
Error in packet
Reason: authorizationError (access denied to that object)

Other proprietary tools have worked, so the remote system is fine.
I need to provide steps to others on how to get V3 requests to work on multiple systems and don't want to build from the source code.
I would like to get it working with open source tools.

### Does anyone know how to get net-snmp to work with V3 with just running installers?

The closest I could find was this older link using older versions:
https://sourceforge.net/p/net-snmp/bugs/2703/

They were able to get an older net-snmp,net-snmp-5.5.0 installer x64 version.
https://sourceforge.net/projects/net-snmp/files/net-snmp%20binaries/5.5-binaries/net-snmp-5.5.0-2.x64.exe/download

With an older Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11895

With an older ActivePerl-5.22

With an older Win64OpenSSL-0_9_8y
https://archives.darenet.org/misc/openssl-bin/Win32OpenSSL_Light-0_9_8y.exe

But when I tried to follow those steps, I just got a crash dialog when running an snmpget.

Comment: NET-SNMP stops producing its Windows builds years ago, so you shouldn't expect anything to work. The old installers depend on very old OpenSSL bits, so you shouldn't use them either. If you do want to run SNMP v3 agent on Windows, you need to support yourself by compiling/modifying NET-SNMP source code, or find free/commercial alternatives.

Comment: You should post and accept your answer. That's how this site works.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Lex, good to know it's not possible with net-snmp. I didn't see anything that stated that on the net-snmp site.

In case anyone is looking for an alternative to net-snmp I found:
SNMPSoft’s snmpget. ezfive.com/snmpsoft-tools/snmp-get
Quick to install and easy to use.

Example:
SnmpGet.exe -r:"10.24.85.113" -v:3 -sn:admin -ap:MD5 -aw:11111111 -pp:DES -pw:11111111 -o:.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0

SnmpGet v1.01 - Copyright (C) 2009 SnmpSoft Company
[ More useful network tools on snmpsoft.com ]
OID=.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0
Type=OctetString
Value=Bla-Bla-Bla